# Azure storage doesn't consider my iot-hub a trusted service?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-iot-hub

I have been using Azure iot-hub to receive data from a number of IoT devices, and have been successful using the default/built-in endpoint to read the data/do work on it.  I recently wanted to start saving the data for possible analytics in the future so I created an azure storage account within the same resource group.  I have gone through all the walkthroughs on how to set up the routes and have one functioning properly to send the data to the messages/events built-in endpoint (since it is disabled as the default when other routes are created).  However, after I have created the route to my storage account, it doesn't send data to storage unless I switch the storage account to be open to all public networks.

When creating the storage account, there are 3 Networking options- "Public, all networks", "Public, selected networks", and "Private".  The Public, all networks option isn't acceptable since I need the data to be private. The Private option isn't really ideal since none of the other azure resources I've created are currently using a virtual network, and it appears a vnet is required for use with the private option.  So, I selected the "Public, selected networks" option.  Currently, I don't have any outside IPs that I need to give access, but I just need iothub to be able to send data.  There is an option to "Allow trusted Microsoft services access to this storage account" which I have had selected from the beginning.  In my storage firewall/virtual network settings, when I switch my storage account to open to all networks it works fine, but when I have it set on selected networks with the trusted microsoft services option selected it doesn't work.

I guess my questions are:
1. Why doesn't azure consider my iothub a trusted service if it is within the same resource group?
2. Is there some way I could make my iothub a trusted service? 
3. Is there something else I'm missing?

Any thoughts or advice are appreciated.

Comment: As it turns out, the vnet "Private" networking option doesn't work either.  Basically it isn't possible to send data to a private storage from iot hub, it would be nice for them to say that in the docs. Since the Capture feature + an Event Hub turns into about 100$ a month we will probably not use this option.  We will likely try to hook into the back end of stream analytics, sending the raw data as a job.  Will update if that isn't successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of services which are considered "Trusted Azure Services" can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#trusted-microsoft-services

IoT Hub is currently not in the list.

As a workaround you could try the following:

- Create a route in IoT Hub to forward traffic into an Event Hub
- Use the Capture feature of Event Hub to write to storage. According to the list, Event Hub is a trusted service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is very helpful to be able to see the list.  I think I will just create a vnet and get all the other services running together on it rather than adding a new service.